# How to user MaksedInput definitions property in Yii2

Tags: yii2, mask, maskedinput

I need to understand how to use MaskedInput definitions property because i have "phone" field and it have always contain + at start and after it it have contain 10-15 decimal characters. How to implement it?

Comment: That's too broad. Please provide something more (code).

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                'mask' => '99-99999999-9',
            ]) ?>
```

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput.html and https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

You could try

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                'alias' => 'phone',
            ]) ?>
```